# Require assistance/advice in structuring my Firestore DB

Tags: ios, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm still very much a noob and I've been having quite a bit of trouble figuring out how to structure my DB for my Gym/Workout Log app.

The data is to be presented in TableViews with Rows/Sections.The idea is that the end user would first select a day of the week and will name his workout, and he could have multiple workouts under the same day of the week if he wishes. Then, within each workout, he could have multiple exercises, and within each exercise, he could have an array of Weights and Repetitions that need to maintain the order in which they are pushed in (might be some trouble there since I heard that arrays do not always maintain the same order when queried).

There are a few ways that I can go about structuring my DB, but I know that I have to avoid Sub-Collections because although sub-collections will structure my DB beautifully, they are a pain to work with when it comes to reading and performing cascading deletes. I've read that Maps are the way to go, but that's kind of what I''m having trouble with, especially in terms of reading the data. I'm going to post what I have come up with and I'm hoping that someone can suggest on how I can improve the model or what I can change so that I can access the String values of Days, Workouts, Exercises, and Weight/Repetitions as easily as possible, because the way I have it set out, those values are stored as Keys. Much appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can nest up to 100 levels but doesn't mean you should. You can organize your data as a [subcollection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#hierarchical-data) which is a collection within a specific document. You can query across subcollections with the same collection ID using [Collection Group Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). You can find best practices [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices)